# Why does my program write to a file on the first run but not on any future runs of the same program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to write a code that writes to a file. It does for the first run but for any future runs, it doesn't write the user input into the file. Why doesn't this write to the file after the write to file is created? I have an if-else statement to check for a file that already exists. If there is a file, it's supposed to write to it. Otherwise, it creates a file to write to.

```
fstream advice("advice.txt", ios::in|ios::out);
advice.open("advice.txt");

    if (!advice.fail())
    {
        cout << "Found advise file." << endl << "Old advice:" << endl;
        while (getline(advice, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        advice.flush();
        advice.close();
        advice.open("advice.txt", ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
    }
else
    {
        cout << "Could not open the Advise file." << endl<<"Assumption: first run - creating a new file..."<<endl;
        advice.flush();
        advice.close();
        advice.open("advice.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc); //create new file
    }

cout << "Enter your phrase for the next user." << endl;
    getline(cin, line);

    advice <<line << endl;

    advice.flush();
    advice.close();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the *type* of `advice`.  Makes a big difference here.  For example, an `ofstream` has different default mode than `ifstream` or `fstream`.

Comment: Done, sorry I didn't think to include it.

Comment: You may want to use `std::ifstream` when reading the file, then open a new stream variable using `std::ofstream` when writing.  Also, beware of the `trunc` mode, do you really want it (or do you want to append or overwrite)?

Comment: Try adding `advice.clear()` after the `while` loop. My guess is, the stream still has `eof` bit set, which causes all subsequent operations to fail immediately.